# How to parse a JSON path with a "@" in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to output JSON from an API which looks like this.
[image]

I'm using Javascript, the JS I've been using is below the picture.

```
    <p>"stations": [</p>
    <p id="data"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('station.php', function(data) {
  console.log("It is on!");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.stationsinzoneresult.location.length; i++)
      $('#data').append("{ \"point\": [ " + "@x HERE" + "," + "@y HERE" + " ], \"name\":\"" + data.stationsinzoneresult.location[i].name + "\" }," + "<br/>"); 
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't access that with dot notation because of the `@`, but you can use bracket notation:

```
data.stationsinzoneresult.location[i]['@x']
```